# Where is the schematool command in Sitecore Publishing Service 2.0?

Tags: publishing-service

So I was installing this morning the Sitecore Publishing Service 2.0 package available [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service/20/Sitecore_Publishing_Service_20_Initial_Release.aspx) but when I got to the step of running the database schema upgrade(cmd is schematool.exe upgrade) I noticed it didn't come with the package.

Since I didn't had this issue running with version 1.1 I downloaded the 1.1 package and noticed that the schematool.exe executable is part of the package itself.

Anyone know what extra steps need to be made to run it in 2.0? Anything I should install or is it missing from the package itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Publishing%20Service/20/Sitecore%20Publishing%20Service%2020%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes), "The schema tools are now part of the Publishing Service."

Therefore the command should now be:

```
Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host schema upgrade
```

This is also covered in the installation guide for Sitecore Publishing Service 2.0. The guide was recently updated (yesterday in fact), so maybe there were errors in earlier versions.